# Convert Blender Render materials to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am doing the [Introduction to Camera Tracking in Blender](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/) tutorial by Blender Guru. Starting at 47:20, he does things with materials and textures in Blender Render that I don't understand (I have decided to focus my learning on the Cycles Render Engine). It ends at about 51:00. How do I create these materials in Cycles?

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Here is my result from camera view showing only the hole:

[image]

The first thing I did was flip all normals by keying <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*, <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*, going to *Toolshelf > Shading/UVs tab > Shading dropdown* and clicking *Flip Normals*. This ensures that the textures display properly on the inside of the tube.

[image]

Second and lastly, I modified your node setup to this:

[image]

For the *Image Textures*, *red_rock* is still on top and *brown_dirty* on the bottom. I did not change how the color is integrated, but they now have bump mapping for each that is averaged by a *Converter > Vector Math* node. The additional *Separate XYZ* and other top nodes add the *Ambient Occlusion* shadows. *Separate XYZ* makes the darkness align to the local *Z-Axis*. The *Gradient Texture* mostly serves to convert the z vector to a *Fac:* value for the *ColorRamp*, which decides how much black and color there is. The *MixRGB*'s bottom color input actually decides what color appears in the tube.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: I think I understand your node set up and thanks a lot. Maybe there is one thing I don't understand and that is why you take the "generated coordinates" instead of the UV coordinates ?

Comment: @OldMan For whatever reason, UV coords didn't work right with the rest of the top nodes. I'm sorry that I can't give a better explanation.

Comment: Could you maybe edit your answer and include your comment. Maybe somebody else can shed some light on this and then we both have learned something :)